java locale chinese simplified number conversion
I am trying to display numbers in the appropriate locale.   The below code appears to work fine for 'ar-SA'...but I am unable to get a similar response for 'zh-CN' locale:
    Locale loc = new Locale("ar","SA");
    NumberFormat nfloc = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
    System.out.println("number (Arabic): " + nfloc.format(333));
    
    loc = new Locale("zh","CN");
    nfloc = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
    System.out.println("number (Chinese Simplified): " + nfloc.format(333));

I get the following output:
number (Arabic): ٣٣٣
number (Chinese Simplified): 333
...but I am looking for :
number (Arabic): ٣٣٣
number (Chinese Simplified): 三百三十三
I've gone down the road of using ICU4J...but it's less than ideal with a 13meg jar.  I was hoping to get it to work with just java.util.Locale.

Just using google translate seems to give "Three hundred thirty-three" for 三百三十三 whereas ٣٣٣ gives me 333: are you trying to translate into what is effectively a "full sentence"/number represented by "words" (i.e. 3 hundred 3 tens 3, each word being a character in zh-CN)? The latter may need more than NumberFormat can do, but that would be a difference to handle (printing those "placement markers"). You could well write your own that maps each roman digit 0-9 into zh-CN and adds those "placement markers" per digit. Lots of "quotes" used for lack of better terms off-hand.

looking for the chinese 'value' of 333...which should be 三百三十三.    In a similar vein as the arabic that I posted.   ٣٣٣ and 三百三十三 should equal the 'value' of 333...not the 'wording'.

As a side note: you don't need to bake ICU4J into your jarfile, you could bundle it separately and load it at runtime. Then updates wouldn't need to re-download ICU4J. Note that "٣٣٣", "三百三十三", "333", and "333.0" are all (String) representations of (Number) 333, they aren't actual numbers that are evaluated (i.e. the reverse is its own problem). You might need a different locale than zh-CN to get the "full-text" version you seek.

yeah...I would like to avoid ICU4J if possible...but thanks for the tip.    It seems odd that java.util.Locale works great for arabic...but not chinese (simplified).

It may be that "simplified" uses roman numerals (as they seem to be in use on things like wechat / etc, in addition to meshing well with any current number systems), but a more "formal" locale uses this convention. Have you tried the other chinese locales?

yeah...I tried zh-CN, zh-HK, zh-TW, zh-CNS ....none of them work.

Even ug_CN (Arabic) doesn't

In theory, Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-CN-u-nu-hans") should force Chinese numerals, but it doesn’t work for me in Java 22.

Yep...same here with regards to Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-CN-u-nu-hans")...doesn't work for Java 17 either.

BTW according UnicodePlus, these codes are in the category Other Letter while the arabic ones are Decimal Number (aka digits) (if I write 333 using  Locale.US I would not expect getting Three hundred and thirty-three; or Dreihundertdreiunddreißig if using Locale.GERMANY [but I do not know Chinese])

Interesting...is there a 'Decimal Number' category in UnicodePlus for Chinese numerals?

I'm not seeing where java.text.NumberFormat nor java.text.DecimalFormat is able to accomodate the formatting of a double to Chinese numeric 'values'...regardless of UnicodePlus category.
